# button positioning relative to background image

Tags: android

So I may be going around this the wrong way.

But I have a splash image with 'buttons' already drawn on it. And I figured I would place invisible buttons on the top of the image.

But wont different screen sizes etc make this an impossible task? The background-image is stretched to fill the whole screen.

Comment: If the visibility is set to gone, the invisible views will take no space at all

Comment: There's no way to do what you want to do if you want to use a fullscreen image.  You should make a generic background image with real Buttons.